# How to extract numbers from a separate CSV file in Java while being limited to scanners and no arrays?

Tags: java

I've been messing with this for hours and can't get it to work. My professor wants us to use a scanner to extract the review star rating from the separate CSV file.

**the CSV file is formatted as such:**
`"this is my review blablahblah, ",4` (4 being the rating)

**And this is what I have so far:**

```
import java.util.Scanner; // Needed for the Scanner class
import java.io.*;         // Needed for the File class

public class HotelReviews {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final String ERR_MSG = "Invalid data";
        // Create a Scanner object for keyboard input.
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        final String CSV_FILE = "tripadvisor_hotel_reviews_mini.csv";
        File csvFile = new File(CSV_FILE);
        Scanner csvIn = new Scanner(csvFile);
        // Skips first line
        csvIn.nextLine();
        // Read lines from the file until no more are left.
        while (csvIn.hasNext()) {
            int pos = 0;
            int oneStar = 0;
            int twoStar = 0;
            int threeStar = 0;
            int fourStar = 0;
            int fiveStar = 0;
            String line = csvIn.nextLine();
            // Star rating check
            if (line.charAt(pos) == ',') {
                if (csvIn.hasNextInt()) {
                    if (pos == 1)
                        oneStar++;
                    else if (pos == 2)
                        ;
                    {
                        twoStar++;
                    }
                    if (pos == 3)
                        threeStar++;
                    else if (pos == 4)
                        ;
                    {
                        fourStar++;
                    }
                    if (pos == 5) {
                        fiveStar++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // Close the file.
        csvIn.close();
    }
}
```

Please excuse my poor indentation, I've been struggling with that.
I need to put the amount each review gets into a separate print statement (ex: four 3 star reviews), but I haven't added that yet.
A lot of answers I see include arrays, but we haven't learned those yet and aren't supposed to use them.
Anything will help, thank you!

I'm so lost that I don't even know what to try. I'm a beginner and my professor's teaching style doesn't work with me.

Comment: In real life, I'd say use a CSV parser to handle the file, then pick the last field. If you're not allowed to do this, you could just read each line and take the last character, and then increase the counter for that character. Skip trailing white space if you want to make it more robust. In your loop, you never increase `pos`, so you keep looking at the first character.

Comment: "*Please excuse my poor indentation..."* -- why apologize? Why try to make it harder for others to understand your code than it needs to be? Please instead fix the indentation when posting. I've done it for you this time, but in the future, this should be ***your*** responsibility.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Yeah, that's my bad. I'm a beginner and am still having a hard time wrapping my head around the rules surrounding it. I appreciate you fixing it, thank you.

Comment: `"this is my review blablahblah, ",4` looks funny, but if all of your lines are truly in this format, try to split on `"\","`. `while(csvIn.hasNext())
    {
        String line = csvIn.next();
        System.out.println(line.split("\",")[1].trim());
        ...
    }`

Comment: fwiw, the body of a `main` method that will put your review scores into a `Map` of counts: `try (Scanner s = new Scanner(Files.newBufferedReader(Path.of(args[0]))).useDelimiter("\\R")) {Map<String, Long> reviewScores = s.tokens().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(line ->line.replaceAll(".*(\\d+)", "$1"), Collectors.counting()));System.out.println(reviewScores);}`

Comment: You also have dangling semicolons in your else statements. Those are short-circuiting the statements and you will want to get rid of them.